# reactjs store reducer not correctly implemented

Tags: reactjs

I got in my reactjs app this error:

`Store does not have a valid reducer. Make sure the argument passed to combineReducers is an object whose values are reducers.`

my store looks like this:

```
import {applyMiddleware, combineReducers, createStore} from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

const store = createStore(
    combineReducers({}),
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
);

export default store;
```

how should it look like correctly?

Comment: Well, you don't have any reducers in your store, so ofcourse its not valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get this error until you add a reducer to `combineReducers` see below example.

**Counter reducer '/reducers/counter'**

```
export default (state = 0, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'INCREMENT':
     return state + 1;
   case 'DECREMENT':
     return state - 1;
   default:
     return state;
  }
};
```

**Store**

```
import {applyMiddleware, combineReducers, createStore} from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import counter from '/reducers/counter';

const store = createStore(
    combineReducers({counter}),
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
);

export default store;
```

Comment: for what do I need a reducer?

Comment: @Felix For managing state, you should google `redux` and figure out if you actually need to use it. See this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/lOmyoxQw1

Answer (score 1):

If you are not going to use reducer decomposition, then why are you using combineReducers? Simply define a function like the following to be your sole reducer and pass it to createStore().

```
(state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Or simply the following if you just want it to work:

```
(state = {}, action) => state
```